# nvidia-settings does not work since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, nvidia-settings

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, it is impossible to change any parameter in nvidia-settings without this program crashing.

nvidia-settings is starting correctly but if I try to change any parameter (and clicking "apply"), it will crash with the following message:

```
ERROR: Error querying target relations

The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 830 error_code 2 request_code 157 minor_code 25)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

This error happens even when there is no change in configuration (changing resolution and setting back then clicking apply)

My config:

Graphics card: GeForce GTX 460

Dual screen

OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.117

nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Comment: Did you remember to install the proprietary NVidia driver from `Additional Drivers` again if you performed a clean install? Was this an in-place upgrade (i.e. no use of a LiveCD/LiveUSB). If the latter is true, you may have a broken install. In-place upgrades of Ubuntu and other operating systems are notoriously unstable.

Comment: It was an in-place upgrade. And the upgrade did fail... But except this bug and a firefox shortcut bug everything else seems fine. Error messages I copy pasted during upgrade (warning: french) http://paste.ubuntu.com/7298770/

Comment: Bugs related to in-place upgrades tend to be very specific to your personal machine/installation and therefore difficult to debug. If you can find the time, you may want to do a backup of `/home` and perform a clean install. If you select "Something Else" during the installation, you could then have seperate `/` and `/home` partitions, so future clean installs do not result in loss of files.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by installing the more recent version of the nvidia driver from the repository.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Comment: The problem was that the latest version of nvidia-settings is 331 while the nvidia-current package still point to the nvidia-304 driver.